# Find the remainder when a large number is divided by 35.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I don't know why I am wrong with this problem. Here is what I did: The last two digit of $6^{2006}$ is 36. So the answer should be 1.

> Find the remainder when $6^{2006}$ is divided by 35.

Comment: $6^{2006}\equiv 36^{1003}\equiv 1^{1003}\equiv 1\pmod{35}$.

Comment: Thanks. So the answer sheet is wrong.

Comment: Your reasoning is wrong, for example $136\equiv 31 \mod 35$.

Comment: It is not true that the last two digits of $6^{2006}$ are $36$, they are $56$, but that does not help you with $6^{2006} \pmod {35}$

Comment: The last two digits of $6^{2006}$ are $56$, not $36$. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6%5E(2006)+mod+100

Comment: @FSK It seems that your answer sheet says $1$, and that's indeed the answer. What's wrong?

Comment: 136 mod 35 = 31 That trick, taking the last digit, only works for 10 in base  10, 2 in base 2, etc.

Comment: One way to show that $6^{2006} \equiv 56 \pmod{100}$: $6^7 \equiv 6^2 \pmod{100}$, so the last two digits of $6^n$ repeat on a cycle of length $5$ for $n\geq2$; but $2006 \equiv 1 \pmod5$, so $6^{2006} \equiv 6^6 \equiv 56 \pmod{100}$.

Comment: For this type of problem in general, see [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand)

Answer (score 13):

Not sure how you've figured "The last two digits of $6^{2006}$ are $36$", but here's my approach:

$$6^2\equiv36\equiv1\pmod{35}\implies6^{2006}\equiv(6^2)^{1003}\equiv1^{1003}\equiv1\pmod{35}$$

Comment: The last two digits of $6^{2006}$ are $56$, not $36$. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6%5E(2006)+mod+100

Comment: @user236182: And even if they were $36$, it still wouldn't imply that the remainder of the number divided by $35$ is $1$.

Answer (score 4):

HINT :

$6^{2006}=36^{1003} \equiv 1^{1003} $ (mod 35)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach. For solving problems$\pmod{N}$, we can try finding the prime factors of $N$, then solving the problem modulo each of those factors. Sometimes this is easier than directly solving $\pmod{N}$.

Then something called the *Chinese Remainder Theorem* lets us combine the results for each factor to produce the result for $N$.

In this case the prime factors of $35$ are $5$ and $7$. Since $6 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$ and $6 \equiv -1 \pmod{7}$, we see straightaway that:

- $6^{2006} \equiv 1\pmod 5$
- $6^{2006} \equiv 1 \pmod 7$  , since $2006$ is even

The Chinese Remainder Theorem tells us that, given congruences $N \equiv a \pmod{p}$ and $N \equiv b \pmod {q}$ , then there is a *unique* $x$ such that $N \equiv x \pmod{pq}$, and it is the same $x$ for all $N$ (and this generalizes to multiple factors).

In the general case you may have to follow an algorithm or use brute force to find $x$. In this case it is right in front of us: letting $N = 1$ satisfies our two congruences. So $1 \pmod{35}$ is the answer we are looking for.